# How to make rkhunter only check for rootkits, and nothing else

Tags: linux, rkhunter

At the time, I check my system like this:

```
rkhunter --check --enable all --disable none --report-warnings-only
```

Or shorter version:

```
rkhunter -c --enable all --disable none --rwo
```

But this gives me warning messages like this one:

> ```
> Warning: The command '/usr/bin/GET' has been replaced by a script:
> /usr/bin/GET: a /usr/bin/perl -w script text executable
> ```

Which - to me - is of no importance, I want to check only for rootkits, and nothing else. But I can't seem to find the proper option to make this work.

How to make [`rkhunter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rkhunter) only scan for rootkits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rkhunter --enable rootkits --rwo
```

will run only the rootkit tests. This can also be set up in the configuration file. The [README](http://rkhunter.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rkhunter/rkhunter/files/README) file has all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the accepted answer could be defining alias.

In order to make it also update first, I would suggest defining the following alias:

```
alias rkhunter='sudo rkhunter --update && \
                echo && \
                sudo rkhunter --check --enable rootkits --skip-keypress --report-warnings-only'
```

I will also suggest you to sometimes do a complete check, e.g. with the such alias:

```
alias rkhunter-all='sudo \rkhunter --propupd && \
                    echo  && \
                    sudo \rkhunter --update && \
                    echo && \
                    sudo \rkhunter --check --enable all --disable none --skip-keypress --report-warnings-only'
```